# Print the lines between two lines that has the same pattern using bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have a text file containing with string pattern 'OG' -

```
OG
ANNNFKSODJFHFJ
SSJSJKSKJSAJAS
SSSSSSSSSSSSFA
OG
FALJFNAFAFNAFJL
AFJLJSLJFLFSLFL
ASJFAJFAKFKAFKK
OG
AJSFLJASFLSFLFF
SJFLAFLAFLFLAFA
ASASFASFOFLJAJF
```

I want to print the lines between the first two lines that has 'OG' as string pattern, i.e. The result should be -

```
ANNNFKSODJFHFJ
SSJSJKSKJSAJAS
SSSSSSSSSSSSFA
```

Here, any suggestions using 'sed' or 'awk'. I don't want to use printing by line number but rather with pattern search.

I tried using awk, but not working -

`awk '/^OG/{flag=1;next}/^OG/{flag=0}flag' file.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
$ awk '/^OG/ {if(go) exit; go=1; next} go {print}' file.txt
ANNNFKSODJFHFJ
SSJSJKSKJSAJAS
SSSSSSSSSSSSFA
```

Comment: @markp-fuso Yes, but it's deliberate, for clarity.

Comment: Suppose if instead of pattern 'OG', I have different pattern with numbers say for example 'OG0029_PC', does this command choose lines similarly, considering that 'OG' is the starting pattern of the the line.

Comment: Remove the `$` in `/^OG$/` if you want to match only `OG` at the beginning of lines. And also please edit your question to show an example where `OG` is followed by different strings.